# I want to add product to shopify using javascript and csv/excel sheet

Tags: javascript, csv, automation, shopify, node-csv-parse

I have exported a CSV file from my Shopify store. My goal is to automatically add any new products added to the CSV file to my store. To achieve this, I have installed the csv-parser and shopify-api-node packages in my Node.js environment. Additionally, I have created an app with the same name as my store in the 'Apps and sales channels' section of my Shopify store. I have generated the admin API key and API secret for this app. Below is the code I am trying to run:

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const fs = require("fs");
const parse = require("csv-parser");
const app = express();
// ===================
const Shopify = require("shopify-api-node");
// ===================
// middleware
dotenv.config();

// codes will be here
// ===================
const shopify = new Shopify({
shopName: process.env.SHOP_NAME,
apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
password: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
});

fs.createReadStream("products.csv")
 .pipe(parse({ columns: true, delimiter: "," }))
 .on("data", (product) => {
  // Add the new product to Shopify
  shopify.product
  .create(product)
  .then((createdProduct) => {
     console.log("Product created:", createdProduct.title);
   })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Failed to create product:", error);
  });
  })
.on("end", () => {
  console.log("Finished adding products");
 });
// ===================
// server

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

After running this code in the terminal, I get an error like this,

```
Failed to create product: HTTPError: Response code 401 (Unauthorized)
at Request.<anonymous> (E:\Web-Development\shopify\codes\natural- 
treasure\node_modules\got\dist\source\as-promise\index.js:118:42)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
code: 'ERR_NON_2XX_3XX_RESPONSE',
 timings: {
start: 1683388059109,
socket: 1683388059113,
lookup: 1683388059169,
connect: 1683388059181,
secureConnect: 1683388059199,
upload: 1683388059199,
response: 1683388059548,
end: 1683388059550,
error: undefined,
abort: undefined,
phases: {
  wait: 4,
  dns: 56,
  tcp: 12,
  tls: 18,
  request: 0,
  firstByte: 349,
  download: 2,
  total: 441
  }
 }
}
```

I am using the shop name from 'shop-name.myshopify.com/admin/', with the API key as 'apikey' and the API secret as the password. I also have the admin API key from the store, but I am not sure how to use it. My endgoal is, I will write a product in the csv/excel file, and it will automatically add that in the shopify store.

Comment: Just to be sure: the name doesn't include /admin

Comment: yes. I am adding the first part of the url as name. for example, abc.myshopify.com/admin. I am taking, "abc" as the shop name.

Comment: `https://abc.myshopify.com` is the shop name